# Omitting the verb in a series of similar sentences

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm writing a story, and English is my second language.
It seems natural for me to write the following:

> Out of 8 children, 7 can go to school by bus.
> John cannot, but he does not mind using his bicycle.

"John cannot" means that John cannot go to school by bus.
Is it correct not to repeat "go to school by bus"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the sentence and understood it. I think that any experienced reader would as well.

I think that your usage is preferable to spelling everything out. The reader does have to retain a memory of what the previous sentences conveyed but that invites their engagement.

However, both are acceptable usages.